# How to extract complex permittivity from a CV measurement?

Tags: measurement, capacitance, dielectric

I can choose from the following measurements:

- Z, theta (impedance and phase angle)
- R + jX (resistance and reactance)
- Cp-Gp (parallel capacitance and conductance)
- Cs-Rs (series capacitance and conductance)
- Cp-D (parallel capacitance and dissipation factor)
- Cs-D (series capacitance and dissipation factor)

Assuming I have such data for a range of frequencies, how do I extract the complex permittivity?

Comment: more a physics stack question but http://www1.lsbu.ac.uk/water/complex_dielectric.html#comp

Comment: The energy of states at a temperature will give you the mean time to fill the states, so you just need the frequency at two (or more points) and a capacitance measuement.  This will be in the notes for a semiconductor physics class for the MOSCAP.

Comment: @JImDearden in the link you provided they mention "loss factor". Is it the same as dissipation factor?

Comment: I think in that reference they are stating the value of the complex part of the permittivity as the loss factor whereas the dissipation factor is defined as the tangent of the angle between the real and complex components.